# Flutter set up confusion

Tags: flutter

I followed the instructions carefully and on my terminal I have wrote:

```
vim .bash_profile
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/kimstephan/Developer/flutter/bin"
~
~
~
~
:wq!
```

After this I exit the terminal and then open a new terminal which then I tried to type as instructed by this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hL7pkX1Pfko&t=303s:

```
flutter --version
```

And I get on my terminal which says:

[image]

My question is, I did exactly what that video asked me to do, but I do not get what I did wrong. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is that the correct path to the flutter dir?   i.e should it have "myname"

Comment: oh no, myname in this case is just like my name the MacBook is registered, let me edit that.